# Recover the last state of activity when phone's return button is pushed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity (let's name it, activity 1), which contains a list with several elements. This activity has a button that allows to add more elements to the list when is pushed. For example, the original state of the list displays 5 elements, each time the button is pushed, two more elements are added to the list (7, 9, 11...).

When a item of the list is pushed, a different activity (let's name it, activity 2) is loaded.

The problem is that if I use the phone's return button to come back to the activity 1, the list is displayed in its original state, namely, only five items.

Is it possible to recover the last status of the list before to go to activity 2? Namely, if the list had 9 elements because de button was pushed 2 times and then I went to the activity 2, is it possible to display the list with those 9 elements when the phone's return button is pushed?

Currently, the list is displayed with the five original elements.

Comment: It depends on how your list adapter is implemented. If you share your code, it would be easier to investigate.

Comment: Do you mean the back button? When you click back the activity should be restored to its previous state by default, so we need to see some code showing exactly how you are moving between activities.